# R base plot polygon map with specified z range?

Tags: r, vector, colors, polygon, raster

I'd like to generate a set of maps with consistent color ramps and am a little bit stuck.  I know how to do what I want for rasters, but not for vector data.

Here's the behavior I want for rasters:

```
require(raster)
r1=raster(matrix(sample(1:50,16),4,4))
r2=raster(matrix(sample(1:100,16),4,4))
plot(r1,col=colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue"))(10),zlim=c(0,100))
plot(r2,col=colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue"))(10),zlim=c(0,100))
```

How do I make similar maps with polygons?

For example:

```
poly1=rasterToPolygons(r1)
poly2=rasterToPolygons(r2)
```

Comment: One option I just came up with is `plot(poly2,col=(colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue"))(10))[round(poly2$layer/10)])` but it feels like a kluge, so I'm wondering if there's a simpler way using the same tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your previous code...
require(raster)
r1=raster(matrix(sample(1:50,16),4,4))
r2=raster(matrix(sample(1:100,16),4,4))
poly1=rasterToPolygons(r1)
poly2=rasterToPolygons(r2)
#################################################


# Color polygons with specific z range:
# Create a function to generate a continuous color palette to work with 
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','white','blue'))

# Make color scale for polygons 1 & 2 by cutting the continuous
# palette object (rbPal) into 50 discrete blocks.
# Each of these blocks will be defined by the polygon layer 
# values in a sequence ranging from 1 to 100 
head(poly1); summary(poly1)
poly1$Col <- rbPal(50)[as.numeric(cut(poly1$layer, breaks = c(seq(1, 100, by=2))))]
poly2$Col <- rbPal(50)[as.numeric(cut(poly2$layer, breaks = c(seq(1, 100, by=2))))]
head(poly1); head(poly2)

# Plot 
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(poly1, col=poly1$Col)
plot(poly2, col=poly2$Col)
```